# When input correct onload html document

Tags: javascript, html, input, onload

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="date_time.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="input"><br>What is the number?</input>
    <button type="button" onclick="getFunction()">Submit</button>


<script>
    function getFunction () {
        var x = document.getElementById('input').value;
        if (x == 32) {
            window.alert("Right answer!");
        }
        else {
            window.alert("Try again.");
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I want to proceed or load a new HTML page when the user clicks on the "submit" button and the input is correct. Any ideas? Maybe JS DOM could help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to add a form tag, and give it a name, id, and action.  The action should point to your desired page.

```
<form name="formname" id="formid" action="mypage.html">
```

Your javascript, where it is true, should simple use:

```
document.getElementById("formid").submit();
```

And it will direct to the action page only when true.